# Rename Parts of fasta-header according to .csv

Tags: python-3.x, bash, bioinformatics, fasta

I want to change parts of my fasta header with a list with parts of a .tsv.

Im not a Bioinformatician just a Microbiologist with beginner skills on bash and python. Thx for the help.

Example:

> Header:
>
> Prevalence_Sequence_ID:1|**ARO:3003072**|RES:mphL|Protein Homolog Model

with

> .tsv
>
> **ARO:3003072**    mphL    mphL is a chromosomally-encoded macrolide phosphotransferases that inactivate 14- and 15-membered macrolides such as erythromycin, clarithromycin, azithromycin.

to

> New header
>
> Prevalence_Sequence_ID:1|**mphL    mphL is a chromosomally-encoded macrolide phosphotransferases that inactivate 14- and 15-membered macrolides such as erythromycin, clarithromycin, azithromycin.**|RES:mphL|Protein Homolog Model

Its possible that the ARO in the fasta header is not given in the .tsv then just ignore it.

Examples fasta

```
>Prevalence_Sequence_ID:1|ARO:3003072|RES:mphL|Protein Homolog Model
MTTLKVKQLANKKGLNILEDS
>gb|ARO:3004145|RES:AxyZ|Achromobacter_insuavis_AXX-A_
MARKTKEESQRTRDRILDAAEHVFLSKG
>Prevalence_Sequence_ID:31298|ARO:3000777|RES:adeF|Protein Homolog Model
MDFSRFFIDRPIFAAVLSILIFI
```

Example .tsv

```
ARO:3003072 mphL    mphL is a chromosomally-encoded macrolide phosphotransferases that inactivate 14- and 15-membered macrolides such as erythromycin, clarithromycin, azithromycin.
ARO:3004145 AxyZ    AxyZ is a transcriptional regulator of the AxyXY-OprZ efflux pump system.
ARO:3000777 adeF    AdeF is the membrane fusion protein of the multidrug efflux complex AdeFGH.
```

Answer (score 0):

If the sequence does not need to be sorted, we can sort fasta with second field, substitute the first space inside .tsv with `|` as a separator and sort it via first field, and then join using proper output format:

```
cat <<EOF >fasta
>Prevalence_Sequence_ID:1|ARO:3003072|RES:mphL|Protein Homolog Model
MTTLKVKQLANKKGLNILEDS
>gb|ARO:3004145|RES:AxyZ|Achromobacter_insuavis_AXX-A_
MARKTKEESQRTRDRILDAAEHVFLSKG
>Prevalence_Sequence_ID:31298|ARO:3000777|RES:adeF|Protein Homolog Model
MDFSRFFIDRPIFAAVLSILIFI
EOF
cat <<EOF >tsv
ARO:3003072 mphL    mphL is a chromosomally-encoded macrolide phosphotransferases that inactivate 14- and 15-membered macrolides such as erythromycin, clarithromycin, azithromycin.
ARO:3004145 AxyZ    AxyZ is a transcriptional regulator of the AxyXY-OprZ efflux pump system.
ARO:3000777 adeF    AdeF is the membrane fusion protein of the multidrug efflux complex AdeFGH.
EOF

join -t'|' -12 -21 -o1.1,2.2,1.3 <(
    <fasta sort -t'|' -k2) <(
    <tsv sed 's/ /|/' | sort -t'|' -k1)
```

If you need the output to be sorted according to fasta, we can number lines with `nl -w1`, then join and then sort the output back using the numbers and remove the numbers:

```
join -t'|' -12 -21 -o1.1,2.2,1.3 <(
    <fasta nl -w1 | sort -t'|' -k2) <(
    <tsv sed 's/ /|/' | sort -t'|' -k1) |
sort -t $'\t' -n -k2 | cut -f2-
```

Answer (score 0):

If you make use of [awk](/questions/tagged/awk), you can do the following steps:

1. Read the full `tsv` file and store all values into an array which is indexed by the first column.
2. Parse the fasta file :

   - if you encounter the header (starts with `>`) then

     - extract the key from the header (first string after `|`)
     - substitute the key with the content of the array
   - print the current line

These steps can also be done in python, but you can easily do it in awk with the following line:

```
awk '# Read the TSV file only
     (NR==FNR) { key=$1; sub(key"[[:space:]]*",""); a[key]=$0; next }
     # From here process the fasta file
     # - if header, perform action:
     /^>/ { match($0,"[|][^|]+"); key=substr($0,RSTART+1,RLENGTH-1);sub(key,a[key]) }
     # print the current line
     1' index.tsv file.fasta > file.new.fasta
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
from Bio import SeqIO

tsvdata = pd.read_csv('example.tsv', sep='/t', header=None, names=['aro','_', 'description'])

for record in SeqIO.parse("example.fasta", "fasta"): 
    fasta_record = str(record).split('|')
    key = fasta_record[1]
    fasta_record[1]=tsvdata[tsvdata['aro']==key]['description'].values[0] 
    print('|'.join(fasta_record))
```

Answer (score 0):

I saved your example Fasta and TSV data into `example.fasta` and `example.tsv`. Here are the input file contents -

```
$ cat example.fasta
>Prevalence_Sequence_ID:1|ARO:3003072|RES:mphL|Protein Homolog Model
MTTLKVKQLANKKGLNILEDS
>gb|ARO:3004145|RES:AxyZ|Achromobacter_insuavis_AXX-A_
MARKTKEESQRTRDRILDAAEHVFLSKG
>Prevalence_Sequence_ID:31298|ARO:3000777|RES:adeF|Protein Homolog Model
MDFSRFFIDRPIFAAVLSILIFI
```

```
$ cat example.tsv
ARO:3003072 mphL    mphL is a chromosomally-encoded macrolide phosphotransferases that inactivate 14- and 15-membered macrolides such as erythromycin, clarithromycin, azithromycin.
ARO:3004145 AxyZ    AxyZ is a transcriptional regulator of the AxyXY-OprZ efflux pump system.
ARO:3000777 adeF    AdeF is the membrane fusion protein of the multidrug efflux complex AdeFGH.
```

```
# import biopython, bioython needs to be installed in your environment/machine
from Bio.SeqIO.FastaIO import SimpleFastaParser as sfp

# read in the tsv data into a dict
with open("example.tsv") as tsvdata:
    tsv_data = {line.strip().split("\t")[0]: " ".join(line.strip().split("\t")[1:])
                for line in tsvdata}

# read input fasta file contents and write to a separate file in real time
with open("example_out.fasta", "w") as outfasta:
    with open("example.fasta") as infasta:
        for header, seq in sfp(infasta):
            aro = header.strip().split("|")[1]  # get ARO for header
            header = header.replace(aro, tsv_data.get(aro, aro))  # lookup ARO in dict and replace if found, otherwise ignore it
            outfasta.write(">{0}\n{1}\n".format(header, seq))
```

Here is the output file contents -

```
$ cat example_out.fasta
>Prevalence_Sequence_ID:1|mphL mphL is a chromosomally-encoded macrolide phosphotransferases that inactivate 14- and 15-membered macrolides such as erythromycin, clarithromycin, azithromycin.|RES:mphL|Protein Homolog Model
MTTLKVKQLANKKGLNILEDS
>gb|AxyZ AxyZ is a transcriptional regulator of the AxyXY-OprZ efflux pump system.|RES:AxyZ|Achromobacter_insuavis_AXX-A_
MARKTKEESQRTRDRILDAAEHVFLSKG
>Prevalence_Sequence_ID:31298|adeF AdeF is the membrane fusion protein of the multidrug efflux complex AdeFGH.|RES:adeF|Protein Homolog Model
MDFSRFFIDRPIFAAVLSILIFI
```